# Can I difference a time series by 3?

Tags: r, time-series, differencing

I need to difference a time series to make it stationary.
Is it feasible to difference it by 3?

Example R code:

```
tsrdiff3=diff(tsr1$LOAD.MW.,difference=3)
```

Comment: Well, it's certainly *possible*, but the practical situations where that would be both appropriate and useful would be rare. Can you  give more information about the circumstances?

Comment: Note, that your code produces 3rd order difference, not the difference at lag 3. I.e. compare outputs of `diff(1:10,difference=3)` and `diff(1:10,lag=3)`. While difference at lag 3 might be feasible for certain seasonality patterns, the 3rd order difference is much less feasible, since this entails that the original process is integrated of order 3, which is very very rare.

Comment: Is it correct that you intend differences of *order 3* (third differences), rather than differences of *lag 3*?